# Could someone explain me how to react to this type of question?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

I have solely marked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449927/a-z0-9-regexp-matching-square-brackets) question as an exact duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410430/angularjs-alpha-only-regex-is-accepting-special-characters) question . And I know that question I linked is also an duplicate. You know, it's easy for us to find our own answer through some search query.

After sometime someone commented that "the question you linked is also a duplicate of another". I fully agree with that comment and replied that, I'm ready to mark the question of mine as duplicate of the question you linked". And I [did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410430/angularjs-alpha-only-regex-is-accepting-special-characters) according to his comment.

My questions are why people asking me to reopen that particular question. Why don't we give the credit to the one who posted first on Stack Overflow? Why we need to reopen this question?

In the mean time, a user commented that

> when someone is searching for a similar problem because of the descriptive title and it's not tagged to a specific flavor (he mean about languages)

Does the title plays a major role?

Comment: The comment asking you to reopen the question seems to be gone?

Comment: i received a downvote

Comment: But that doesn't mean the question should be reopened, does it? People downvote for all sorts of reasons  (or no reason at all, sometimes)

Comment: Ah, I see now. Given that the original question has received more attention, it would have been more prudent to close it the other way round. This way, it looks like you're directing people to the question with your answer. Something to consider in the future.

Comment: The voting in that Q+A is stunning, [regex] is a very strange land.

Comment: @Pekka웃 i don't want it to be mine. You could reopen that question and mark as a duplicate of the one where the other mentioned. Oh, you mean that i marked it as duplicate of mine i would receive more upvotes? I don't care about upvotes, please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/users

Comment: @HansPassant i answered these kind of questions two or three times but even a single won't receive more than 5 upvotes :( Why? is that the screenshot on that answer attracts more people? or is time plays a major role or the question title plays a major role?

Comment: Not just that answer, the question got 28 votes.  I suppose it is popular because everybody can instantly see what he did wrong.

Comment: @AvinashRaj It looks indeed like misuse of your close-privilege for promoting the question with your own answer. There are loads of similar questions such as [1.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4923380/3110638), [2.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6067592/3110638), [3.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18661628/3110638), [4.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19871929/3110638), [5.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21414915/3110638)... also consider, that answers of the one you closed won't be seen by those who instantly skip forward.

Comment: @Jonny5 i already told you that we could easily fetch our answers through search query . I didn't find any questions in google related to that. I get my answer through search query and immediately marked it as duplicate. I i found any answer related to that, then i'll go for that too. I don't want any reputations from that. The op of the original question i linked, acceptted my answer. So i can't able to delete that. If he unaccepts than i'll delete mine.

Comment: And i won't never get any reputations. Please note that i marked that question as duplicate because it's duplicate, **not in terms of rep-earning**.

Comment: `misuse of your close-privilege` ?? Dupe-hammer is for marking the duplicate questions as duplicate. Why i need to think that this question receives more number of votes so we don't close.